# How can I install sendgrid app in Heroku using git (PHP)?

Tags: heroku, sendgrid

At the top of my index.php file I have:

```
require('sendgrid-php/SendGrid_loader.php');
```

And at the bottom I use this code to send the email:

```
    <?php
       if(isset($_POST['submit']))
          {


          $sendgrid = new SendGrid('app11445063@heroku.com', 'password');

         $mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
          $mail->
             addTo('email@gmail.com')->
             setFrom('app11445063@heroku.com')->
             setSubject('Subject goes here')->
             setText('Hello World!')->
             setHtml('<strong>Hello World!</strong>');

          $sendgrid->
            smtp->
             send($mail);
    }
 ?>
```

I can't get the code to send an email out.  I have the proper account from SendGrid and Heroku.  The required files are in my directory. Do I have the wrong path to the required file?

Comment: Could you provide us with the error message you're getting back?  It will definitely help debugging.  Also PHP version would help too.

Comment: Hello Swift.  Thanks for responding.  I do not have any error messages at this time.  It's just not doing anything when I click submit.  Do you know much about how Heroku works?  Do I need to somehow install the required library into their servers?

Comment: PHP version:  5.3.1
Apache Version: 2.2.22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the SendGrid library was not in the repository in Heroku.  Just do a "git status" and add the directory to the commit and then push the directory to Heroku.  Make sure you also have the correct path in the "include" in your PHP code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by this? I believe I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with [Sendgrid's PHP lib](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php). If you are using SMTP (you must if using heroku) you must also have swiftmailer installed. Otherwise the line 25 won't work in sendgrid-php/SendGrid/Smtp.php

```
public function __construct($username, $password){
/* check for SwiftMailer,
 * if it doesn't exist, try loading
 * it from Pear
 */
if (!class_exists('Swift')) {
  require_once 'swift_required.php';
}
```